# Can we implement the browser plugin to do the automation for sites?

Tags: plugins, browser, air, automation, adobe

Can we implement the browser plugin to do the automation for sites?
I want to implement an standalone application either a browser plugin or desktop application which can do the automated tasks, basically:
1. Log in to the site
2. Navigate across the pages by filling forms if any.(navigation is not the same for all the use cases) 
3. Do the action & download the files to local system.

can we implement this as a browser plugin. Pro's & con's is helpful.

I'm also looking at adobe AIR. Please suggest.
Note: I don't want the users to see what's happening n the browser.

Edit: I want this to be cross platform windows, linux, Mac...
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Selenium IDE, a FireFox plug-in. It is free and pretty easy to use until you get deeper into it's functionality which requires coding (e.g. C#, Javam Ruby and others).

Basic functionalities:
1) Record
2) Playback
3) Assert values
4) Screenshot on failure
5) Setup multiple variables as data source
6) Export a test cases or test suite
7) Yes, it supports use cases and they can be downloaded to playback or imported as test cases

Note on user's visibility to web page activities - the browser has to be opened for this version of tool. There is another version that can automate from a hub or central machine which is able to open multiple browsers or Operating Systems, but, that's just something to keep in mind if you need something more that record and playback page navigation.

Selenium IDE: http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/